# ElasticSearch analyzer that allows for query both with and without hypens

Tags: elasticsearch

How do you construct an analyzer that allows you to query fields both with *and* without hyphens?

The following two queries must return the same person:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Jay-Z"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "jay z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use a [mapping character filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) in order to replace the hyphen with a space. Basically, like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "hyphens"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "hyphens": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "-=>\\u0020"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then we can check what the analysis pipeline would yield using the `_analyze` endpoint:

For `Jay-Z`:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tests/_analyze?pretty&analyzer=my_analyzer' -d 'Jay-Z'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "jay z",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 5,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}
```

For `jay z`:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tests/_analyze?pretty&analyzer=my_analyzer' -d 'jay z'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "jay z",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 5,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}
```

As you can see the same token is going to be indexed for both forms so your `term` query will work with both forms as well.